# FireFLY EGL config Problem

Tags: ros-lunar

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello there,  I'm running Ros lunar full desktop on this FireFly RK3399.  First problem, when i type into the terminal:
`rosrun rviz rviz`, it kicks up this error:

```
firefly@firefly:~$ rosrun rviz rviz
[ INFO] [1528702646.473572157]: rviz version 1.12.16
[ INFO] [1528702646.473719158]: compiled against Qt version 5.5.1
[ INFO] [1528702646.473746867]: compiled against OGRE version 1.9.0 (Ghadamon)
Cannot find EGLConfig, returning null config
Unable to find an X11 visual which matches EGL config 0
Could not initialize OpenGL for RasterGLSurface, reverting to RasterSurface.
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Thanks for any insight you can provide,

Robert

PS the Firefly RK3399 is running Ubuntu 16.04 and it's a 64 bit OS

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/293846/firefly-egl-config-problem/) by [Robert_d1968](https://answers.ros.org/users/35822/robert_d1968/) on ROS Answers with karma: 15 on 2018-06-11

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Are you sure you have a working OpenGL driver for your computer, and that it is configured correctly? I'd suggest you go through http://wiki.ros.org/rviz/Troubleshooting and update this question with the results.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2018-06-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-06-12**:
Looking around for info on OpenGL and the RK3399 shows that this is not something that is easily setup, especially if you're not using the FireFly provided rootfs.

**Comment by [Robert_d1968](https://answers.ros.org/users/35822/robert_d1968/) on 2018-06-12**:
You were exactly right about OpenGL, It was running an image from them, and it was not installed. once I got it installed rviz works like a charm now.

Thank you so much for the help  :)

Robert